# Encode XDocumnet form win-1251 to utf-8

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, linq-to-xml, encode

I try to convert XDocument from win-1 to utf-8. But in raw-view russian characters have bad view.

```
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false,false);

        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter("F:\\File", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
        document.Save(xmlTextWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Close();
        xmlTextWriter = null;

        string text = File.ReadAllText("F:\\File", Encoding.Default);
        XDocument documentcode = XDocument.Parse(text);
        xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(_Stream, encoding);
        documentcode.Save(xmlTextWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Flush();

        _Stream.Position = 0;
        Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
```

This is the raw-view in SOAPUI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><StatObservationList><StatObservation><ObjectID>0b575ec1-7dea-41c4-a1f0-287190715ed2</ObjectID><Name>РўРµСЃС‚РѕРІРѕРµ СЃС‚Р°С‚РЅР°Р±Р»СЋРґРµРЅРёРµ</Name><Code>GPPCode42</Code></StatObservation><StatObservation><ObjectID>3a871ea1-06ee-4991-a263-d643b424bdd4</ObjectID><Name>РњРёРЎРџ</Name><Code /></StatObservation></StatObservationList>
```

Comment: You're openning the file with Encoding.Default. Are you sure it's the same as you saved it? Try openning it with Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251") as it's the encoding used while saving it

Comment: What do you mean convert?  It's not clear what you're trying to do.  An `XDocument` (or any string in memory) doesn't have an encoding until you encode it - i.e. until you write it to a stream.  As an aside, you shouldn't be using `XmlTextWriter`, you should create a writer using `XmlWriter.Create`.

Comment: i used XmlTextWrite to delete BOM.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're trying to do.  It sounds like you just need `document.Save(_Stream)` - what's the problem with that?

Comment: I used document.Save(_Stream), and got the same results in raw-view. I saw on forums this code  `string text = File.ReadAllText("F:\\File", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            document.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"); 
            XDocument documentcode = XDocument.Parse(text);`but it's not work/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it now.  The text in your `XDocument` has, for whatever reason, been decoded incorrectly using Windows-1251.

Ideally, you need to go back to the source and ensure it is decoded properly (with UTF8).  Converting this may not be an entirely loss-free process, as there are code points in the UTF8 that don't have a representation in Windows-1251 (a quick glance at the [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) shows nothing for `0x98`, for example).

However, to convert this after the fact the simplest way is just to get the text back, get the bytes for the encoding it was decoded with and then decode those with the correct encoding:

```
var windows1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

var originalBytes = windows1251.GetBytes(document.ToString());
var correctXmlString = utf8.GetString(originalBytes);
var correctDocument = XDocument.Parse(correctXmlString);
```

Comment: russian character in win1251 have full representation utf8, i cheked it.

Comment: That might be true, but the reverse isn't - and that's the problem you *could* have here.  The text you have was *originally* encoded with UTF8, but it has been incorrectly decoded using Windows-1251.